# correct websocket connection closure

Tags: go, websocket, gorilla

I wrote a connection closure function. It sends a closing frame and expects the same in response.

```
func TryCloseNormally(wsConn *websocket.Conn) error {
    closeNormalClosure := websocket.FormatCloseMessage(websocket.CloseNormalClosure, "")
    defer wsConn.Close()
    if err := wsConn.WriteControl(websocket.CloseMessage, closeNormalClosure, time.Now().Add(time.Second)); err != nil {
        return err
    }
    if err := wsConn.SetReadDeadline(time.Now().Add(time.Second)); err != nil {
        return err
    }
    _, _, err := wsConn.ReadMessage()
    if websocket.IsCloseError(err, websocket.CloseNormalClosure) {
        return nil
    } else {
        return errors.New("Websocket doesn't send a close frame in response")
    }
}
```

I wrote a test for this function.

```
func TestTryCloseNormally(t *testing.T) {
    done := make(chan struct{})
    exit := make(chan struct{})
    ctx := context.Background()

    ln, err := net.Listen("tcp", "localhost:")
    require.Nil(t, err)
    handler := HandlerFunc(func(conn *websocket.Conn) {
        for {
            _, _, err := conn.ReadMessage()
            if err != nil {
                require.True(t, websocket.IsCloseError(err, websocket.CloseNormalClosure), err.Error())
                return
            }
        }
    })

    s, err := makeServer(ctx, handler)
    require.Nil(t, err)
    go func() {
        require.Nil(t, s.Run(ctx, exit, ln))
        close(done)
    }()

    wsConn, _, err := websocket.DefaultDialer.Dial(addr+strconv.Itoa(ln.Addr().(*net.TCPAddr).Port), nil) //nolint:bodyclose
    require.Nil(t, err)
    require.Nil(t, wsConn.WriteMessage(websocket.BinaryMessage, []byte{'o', 'k'}))
    require.Nil(t, TryCloseNormally(wsConn))
    close(exit)

    <-done
}
```

To my surprise, it works correctly. `Readmessage()` reads the closing frame. But in the test, I don't write anything.

1. Is this happening at the `gorilla/websocket` level?
2. Did I write the function correctly? Maybe reading the response frame also happens at the gorilla level.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The function is mostly correct.

Websocket endpoints echo close messages unless the endpoint has already send a close message on its own.  See [Closing Handshake](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/rfc6455#section-1.4) in the Websocket RFC for more details.

In the normal close scenario, an application should expect to receive a close message after sending a close message.

To handle the case where the peer sent a data message before the sending the close message, read and discard data messages until an error is returned.

```
func TryCloseNormally(wsConn *websocket.Conn) error {
    defer wsConn.Close()
    closeNormalClosure := websocket.FormatCloseMessage(websocket.CloseNormalClosure, "")
    if err := wsConn.WriteControl(websocket.CloseMessage, closeNormalClosure, time.Now().Add(time.Second)); err != nil {
        return err
    }
    if err := wsConn.SetReadDeadline(time.Now().Add(time.Second)); err != nil {
        return err
    }
    for {
        _, _, err := wsConn.ReadMessage()
        if websocket.IsCloseError(err, websocket.CloseNormalClosure) {
            return nil
        }
        if err != nil {
            return err
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: thx! By the way, do you think it is necessary to add an argument `func TryCloseNormally(wsConn *websocket.Conn, textErr string) error`. To use it `FormatCloseMessage(websocket.CloseNormalClosure, textErr)`. Is this a common practice of explaining connection closure? Or usually use `""`

Comment: Add the argument if you think the additional string will help with debugging in some way.  Otherwise, the empty string is good.